# Why did Mocha tests failed? Uncaught Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000 (and Mocha's done() called multiple times)

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

When I run mocha tests

```
Running app as a module
Express.js server is listening on port 3000


  server
    homepage
      1) "before all" hook in "server"
      2) should respond to GET


  0 passing (17ms)
  2 failing

  1) server
       "before all" hook in "server":
     Uncaught Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000 (and Mocha's done() called multiple times)
      at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1313:16)
      at listenInCluster (net.js:1361:12)
      at Server.listen (net.js:1447:7)
      at boot (tests/index.js:8:10)
      at Context.<anonymous> (tests/index.js:24:5)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)

  2) server
       homepage
         should respond to GET:
     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
      at /home/miki/azatmardan/ch3/tests/index.js:32:27
```

This is my `index.js` in tests folder

```
const app = require('../app'); 
const port = require('../app').port
const superagent = require('superagent');
const expect = require('expect');
const server = require('http').createServer(app);

const boot = () => {
  server.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.info(`Express server listening on port ${app.get('port')}`)
  })
}
const shutdown = () => {
  server.close()
}

console.info('Running app as a module')
exports.boot = boot
exports.shutdown = shutdown
exports.port = port


describe('server', () => {
  before(() => {
    boot()
  })

  describe('homepage', () => {
    it('should respond to GET', (done) => {
      superagent
        .get(`http://localhost:${port}`)
        .end((error, response) => {
          expect(response.status).to.equal(200)
          done()
        })
    })
  })

  after(() => {
    shutdown()
  })
}
```

How to deal with addres use issue?
Where is Mocha done() called multiple times?

I installed supertest and changed my code. Anyway,it points to almost same problems

```
  0 passing (5ms)
  2 failing

  1) server
       "before all" hook in "server":
     Uncaught Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000 (and Mocha's done() called multiple times)
      at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1313:16)
      at listenInCluster (net.js:1361:12)
      at Server.listen (net.js:1447:7)
      at boot (tests/index.js:8:10)
      at Context.<anonymous> (tests/index.js:24:5)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)

  2) server
       homepage
         should respond to GET:
     TypeError: supertest.get is not a function
```

What is wrong with `.get(`http://localhost:${port}`)` ?

Comment: And *is* anything already bound to that port? Why not use https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest, which uses ephemeral ports?

Comment: Supertest instead of superagent?

Comment: `superagent` and `supertest` are not the same thing. One is for making HTTP requests, the other for testing REST API endpoints in unit tests without an actual server being started.

Comment: Supertest *uses* superagent: *"The motivation with this module is to provide a high-level abstraction for testing HTTP, while still allowing you to drop down to the lower-level API provided by superagent."*